# How to get values from a database to show up in a drop down list?

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

This..

```
while ($line = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $departmentName = trim($line['Department']);
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"$departmentName\" name=\"departmentName\"/>";  
    echo "<br>";
```

yeilds this..

```
<form action="process_case2.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Accounting" name="departmentName"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Administration" name="departmentName"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Finance" name="departmentName"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Human Resources" name="departmentName"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="InfoSystems" name="departmentName"/><br>    
    <input type="submit" value="Legal" name="departmentName"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Marketing" name="departmentName"/><br>      
    <input type="submit" value="Production" name="departmentName"/><br> 
</form>
```

How can I make the first part of this, so that the values are in a drop down list?

Answer (score 0):

This will make what you want:

```
while ($line = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$departmentName[] = trim($line['Department']);
}
?>
<form action="process_case2.php" method="post">

// paste other fields here

<select id="what" class="ever" name="departmentName">
<?php
foreach ($departmentName as $a)
{
?>
<option value="<?= $a; ?>"><?= $a; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>

</select>

// or here

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

On the next page, fetch your data with

```
$_POST['departmentName'];
```

Comment: I have all the other bits, I just need to know what I need to do to this line,echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"$departmentName\" name=\"departmentName\"/>";", In order to make it a dropdown list.

Comment: <input type=\"submit\" value=\"$departmentName\" name=\"departmentName\"/>";

Comment: Well, it's more than this line, as you need to create the select first. If you just copy my answer you'll see it's doing what you want

Comment: You can, of course add your code into it, I've edited the answer for you